# Problema relacionada con bucles en C

Tags: c, bucle-for, bucles, while

El problema consta en cargar números en un arreglo para posteriormente encontrar el menor de todos y imprimirlo por pantalla

para evitar mal entendidos y malversar su tiempo adjunto mi código y la consigna mas la salida en pantalla de la misma

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define max 5

int main(){
    int arreglo[max];
    int contenedor;
    int menor, i, x;

            for (i = 0; i <arreglo[i]; i++){
            printf("Introduzca un numero %d :",i+1);scanf("%d",&arreglo[i]);
            
            if (menor>arreglo[i]){
                menor=arreglo[i];}
        for (contenedor=0;contenedor<arreglo[i];contenedor++){           
}
}
printf("el numero %i es el menor que los %i numeros posteriores\n",menor,contenedor);  

system("pause");
return 0;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende bien cual es tu consulta, ¿Quieres imprimir cual es el menor número ingresado en un arreglo? o ¿Quieres imprimir cuantos números menores existen para cada elemento del arreglo?

Comment: Me parece que tiene que revisar lo que quiere y pasar por su código linea por linea para averiguar lo que hace.  Hay demasidos problemas para una respuesta sencilla.  Por ejemplo, por qué hay una bucle vacia?  Que tiene arreglo[i] la primera vez?  Y hay más.

Comment: ahi agrego la consigna creo que es mas practico asi

Comment: ahora me genero curiosidad tu comentario por lo del arreglo[i]

ósea debería cargar los números que el usuario brinde y guardarlos lo puse asi para que los pida la cantidad de veces que la macro admite 

en su salvo caso ilumíneme no tengo problema en corregir cosas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a la lógica que estás implementando en los bucles, ya que el primer `for` por ejemplo no lo limitas bien (debes declararlo como `for (i=0 ; i<max ; i++)` para que pueda recorrer todo tu array. Luego el segundo `for` lo tienes vacío y además vuelves a cometer el error de no limitar hasta dónde vas a ejecutar esa instrucción.

Como consejo, te recomiendo que antes de empezar a programar intentes aclarar las ideas, pensar qué quieres conseguir, qué variables necesitas, cuál es la lógica más rápida y eficiente para conseguirlo, etc. Es conveniente que cojas papel y bolígrafo y te hagas un pequeño pseudocódigo para ver el posible flujograma que debe tener tu código.

Te dejo el código que debería ser:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define max 5

int main()
{
    int arreglo[max];
    int contenedor = 0, menor = 0, i = 0;

    for (i=0 ; i<max; i++) // Recoge valores
    {
        printf("Introduzca un numero %d: ",i+1);scanf("%d",&arreglo[i]);
    }

    for (contenedor=0 ; contenedor<max ; contenedor++)
    {
        menor = 0;
        for (i=contenedor+1 ; i<max ; i++)
        {
            if (arreglo[contenedor] < arreglo[i])
                menor++;
        }
        printf("El numero %i es menor que otros %i numeros posteriores\n", arreglo[contenedor], menor);   
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

La lógica empleada es:

1. Construyes tu array con todos tus números, por lo que eso con un bucle `for` bastaría. Única y exclusivamente para crear tu array.
2. Una vez que tengas el array con tus datos creados, ejecutas un bucle `for` anidado en otro bucle `for`. ¿Para qué? pues para recorrer todas las posiciones desde el número a estudiar hasta el final. Fíjate que empiezas en `arreglo[0]` y comparas con el resto de posiciones mayores que él (`arreglo[1], arreglo[2], ... , arreglo[max]`). De este modo, cuando vayas a estudiar los número menores que el `arreglo[1]` ya no comparas con el valor de `arreglo[0]` porque según tu enunciado ya no te interesan.
3. Imprimes los resultados de la forma que te sea necesario.

Saludos.

Comment: Si ahora que veo tu código veo que me estaba ahogando en un vaso de agua por no tenerla del todo claro muchas gracias voy a tenerlo en cuenta para proximos proyectos la verdad